# Redirect to another jsp (with response data) after ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

I am using an ajax call to get some places after the call is successfully executed I want to pass that data to another jsp and show it there. my code is

Ajax Call

```
 $(".savebutton").click(function(){
            $.ajax({        
                url: "<c:url value='/findPlaces' />",
                type: 'POST',            
                data:{  
                    preferences : preferences
                },
                success: function(response) 
                {
                    console.log(response);
                    window.location.href = "places";;
                }, 
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
        });
```

Controller Action

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/findPlaces")
public ModelAndView findRecommnededPlaces(HttpServletRequest request) {

    Map< String, Integer> userPreferences = new HashMap< String, Integer>();
    Map< String, Integer> sortedUserPreferences = new HashMap< String, Integer>();

    userPreferences.put("Museum", Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("preferences[Museum]")));
    userPreferences.put("Night Life", Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("preferences[Night Life]")));
    userPreferences.put("Food", Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("preferences[Food]")));

    userService.scalePreferences(userPreferences);  
    sortedUserPreferences = userService.sortPreferences(userPreferences);

    Map< String, Map< String, Integer >> categorisedPlaces = new HashMap< String, Map< String, Integer >>();
    Map<String , List<String>> recommendedPlaces = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<Place> places = searchService.search(new Location(SOURCE_LATITUDE,SOURCE_LONGITUDE), new Location(DEST_LATITUDE,DEST_LONGITUDE));      
    categorisedPlaces = placesService.categorize(places);
    recommendedPlaces = placesService.getRecommendedPlaces(sortedUserPreferences, categorisedPlaces);

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("places");
    model.addObject("recommendedPlaces", recommendedPlaces);
    return model;
}
```

places.jsp

```
<div id="content">
        <c:forEach var="entry" items="${recommendedPlaces}">
            Cat:  ${entry.key} <br/>
            Places: ${entry.value}<br>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
```

How I can redirect to places.jsp and passing the recommndedPlaces there , currently in ajax response I am getting the whole html page

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to do the call in `AJAX`, since you want redirect the user to another page after all... Anyway to get the `recommendedPlaces` as a `JSON` instead of the `HTML` page, use the `@ResponseBody` annotation and return the `Map` instead of the `ModelAndView` Object :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/findPlaces")
public Map<String, List<String>> findRecommnededPlaces(HttpServletRequest request) {

    Map< String, Integer> userPreferences = new HashMap< String, Integer>();
    Map< String, Integer> sortedUserPreferences = new HashMap< String, Integer>();

    userPreferences.put("Museum", Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("preferences[Museum]")));
    userPreferences.put("Night Life", Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("preferences[Night Life]")));
    userPreferences.put("Food", Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("preferences[Food]")));

    userService.scalePreferences(userPreferences);  
    sortedUserPreferences = userService.sortPreferences(userPreferences);

    Map< String, Map< String, Integer >> categorisedPlaces = new HashMap< String, Map< String, Integer >>();
    Map<String , List<String>> recommendedPlaces = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

    List<Place> places = searchService.search(new Location(SOURCE_LATITUDE,SOURCE_LONGITUDE), new Location(DEST_LATITUDE,DEST_LONGITUDE));      
    categorisedPlaces = placesService.categorize(places);
    recommendedPlaces = placesService.getRecommendedPlaces(sortedUserPreferences, categorisedPlaces);

    return recommendedPlaces;
}
```

With the current code in the `success` function, the `recommendedPlaces` returned in the response object will not be sent to the `places.jsp` page. You'll need to add it to the request by using a form or by adding them to the `URL`. That's why I don't really understand why you are using `AJAX` for this request.

Comment: How can I send it in url ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , I removed the ajax call and created a form and worked like a charm

Comment: np, it is probably the best solution